# Keybindings: Mapping them from keyboard to application?

Tags: terminal, x11, osx, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I would like to understand the mapping of keys from Mac OSX to end applications.  What are the mappings, configuration and diagnostic tools at each point for these inferences?  Does the provided step by step inference require modification, additions or subtractions?

I know this seems like it covers many areas, but any insight will be helpful.  Thanks

**General inference path of keys**

- Physical key press -> OSX USB HID driver -> OSX manageable key code
- OSX GUI console -> Terminal.app -> ssh to Linux -> Linux terminal session
- Linux terminal session -> Emacs in terminal session -> Emacs bindings
- OSX GUI console -> X-Quartz -> Emacs

It's my current understanding the following mapping sequence occurs:

**Keyboard -> OSX**

1. OSX USB HID driver interfaces with Keyboard input to iokit daemon
2. Apple provides a shell utility to remap USB HID codes (works in 10.12):

   hidutil property —set ‘{“UserKeyMapping”:[{HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc: 0xHIDSRC, “HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst”: 0xHIDDST, …}.
3. Apple provides a programatic method using Objective-C.  Both methods use the HID keyboards usage IDs in the “Key Table Usage” as offsets from base address 0x700000000.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2450/_index.html.  This 0x700000000 base indexes the table in the USB consortium document (https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/hut1_12v2.pdf).
4. **Karabiner-Elements** is an application which can grab key events by it's own replacement iokit daemon and modify them.
5. Does Apple provide a development tool that shows HID BT key presses?

**OSX -> GUI Console Session**

4. System Preferences->Keyboard->Keyboard to set F1, F2, ... Fn as standard function keys or special Mac OSX specific.
5. System Preferences->Keyboard->Shortcuts to set actions on key combinations
6. System Preferences->Keyboard->Input Sources

   > One of the links in that chain is a file called "keyboard layout",
   >   which translates input (keycodes) into output (characters).
   >   MacOS uses those files to make it possible to type different languages
   >   on the same physical keyboard: one just activates a different keyboard
   >   layout.  **Ukulele** allows modification of this layout.  Commands like Backspace, Tab, cursor key-strokes, etc. are only
   >   partially affected by the keyboard layout file, so to control their
   >   output, you need a different approach.  I also think there are XML files that the can be manually modified here according to some Schemata?

**OSX Applications**

7. **Terminal.app** Preferences->Profiles->Keyboard can change ANSI ASCII "escape codes" for keys.  These escape codes conform to ___ standard?
8. **Terminal.app** Preferences->Profiles->Advanced allows selection of a terminal as "xterm-256color", ....  This effects the mapping how?
9. **Terminal.app** Preferences->Profiles->Advanced->Input allows further modifications checkboxes: Delete sends Ctrl-H, Escape non-ASCII input with Ctrl-V, Paste newlines as carriage returns.

**ssh session with Linux OS**
10. ANSI ASCII stream of bytes is interpreted according to $TERM using terminfo and termcap.  Details?

11. showkey -a, infocmp -CL provide details
12. stty, how does this fit in?
13. Other mappings or diagnostic tools here?

**ssh session with Linux OS and Emacs**
14. Emacs uses M-x describe-bindings to show key bindings

15. Emacs uses (global-set-key) and (define-key) to change key bindings.

**X session with Emacs**

16. X-Quartz interfaces with Mac OSX to map keybindings to applications.
17. xmodmap and xkb can be used to change these bindings.
18. Other mappings or diagnostic tools here?